# How to maintain column width with multiple series in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm attempting to create a chart with both a column series and a line series using highcharts.js.  I'm using `pointPadding` and `groupPadding` to control the column width, per the [documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series%3Ccolumn%3E.pointWidth).
 However, when I include the line series, the columns shrink in width. I think this is because there are more points in the line series than there are in the column series. Is there a way to maintain the column widths with multiple series/series with different lengths?

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    title: {text: 'Histogram'},
    xAxis: {gridLineWidth: 1},
    series: [{
        pointPadding: 0,
        groupPadding: 0,
        type: 'column',
        name: 'Density',
        data: []
    }, {
        type: 'line',
        name: 'Normal Curve',
        data: []
    }]
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle with an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/dgb751hp/

Comment: You can set pointWidth explicitly, but that messes with responsiveness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are right. By adding line series, with more points between columns makes columns narrower. To resolve this, simply add another `xAxis`, link it to the first one and link the second series to the second `xAxis`. Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.xAxis
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.linkedTo

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/9ss538r7/

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!